# Can you freeze a bomb?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Can you use a freeze spell on a bomb to slow/delay the explosion?

If my hogs are trompin around pounding everything into oblivion and stumble across a double bomb, is it possible to drop a freeze spell to give my hogs time to bounce out before they all get disintegrated?

Comment: Great question, although I'd have to applaud your reaction time in freezing a bomb. While bombs do have a delay, so does dropping a spell.

Comment: Great question. @Ellesedil Hardly possible to react, but may be able to anticipate

Comment: @VGO: Sure, but you'd definitely need to be willing to accept the fact that you'd be dropping some freeze spells for little gain if it's just empty space.

Comment: In a war, a previous attack may reveal the location of double bombs, allowing me to freeze counter the bombs with a freeze - if possible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You currently cannot use freeze spells on giant bombs, bombs, air bombs, seeking air mines, or spring traps. You can however use them on hidden teslas which are kind of like a trap. These teslas are frozen even if the spell was dropped before they sprung up. Unfortunately though, you cannot freeze bombs in Clash of Clans as of 7/30/15.

Answer (score 0):

Freezing where you suspect a sudden blow sounds like a wonderful way to make attacks more creative.  Balance it out also if it's a too opportunistic but I think it sounds fantastic!  Though no, best thing you can freeze that is considered a trap is some air or ground skeletons traps.